# failed to download melpa archive

Tags: emacs, melpa

I am using emacs 24.5 and i am trying to add the melpa archive to emacs to my package-archives . when i try `M-x list-packages` i get **failed to download melpa archive** and the list of packages of melpa repo doesn't appear. here is what i got when i try `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Could not create connection to melpa.org:443")
signal(error ("Could not create connection to melpa.org:443"))
error("Could not create connection to %s:%d" "melpa.org" 443)
url-http([cl-struct-url "https" nil nil "melpa.org" nil "/packages/archive-  contents" nil nil t nil t] #[128 "\302\303\304p#\210\300\305\240\210\301p\240\207" [(nil) (nil) url-debug retrieval "Synchronous fetching done (%S)" t] 5 "\n\n(fn &rest IGNORED)"] (nil))
url-https([cl-struct-url "https" nil nil "melpa.org" nil "/packages/archive-  contents" nil nil t nil t] #[128 "\302\303\304p#\210\300\305\240\210\301p\240\207" [(nil) (nil) url-debug retrieval "Synchronous fetching done (%S)" t] 5 "\n\n(fn &rest IGNORED)"] (nil))
url-retrieve-internal("https://melpa.org/packages/archive-contents" #[128 "\302\303\304p#\210\300\305\240\210\301p\240\207" [(nil) (nil) url-debug retrieval "Synchronous fetching done (%S)" t] 5 "\n\n(fn &rest IGNORED)"] (nil) nil nil)
url-retrieve("https://melpa.org/packages/archive-contents" #[128 "\302\303\304p#\210\300\305\240\210\301p\240\207" [(nil) (nil) url-debug retrieval "Synchronous fetching done (%S)" t] 5 "\n\n(fn &rest IGNORED)"] nil nil nil)
url-retrieve-synchronously("https://melpa.org/packages/archive-contents")
url-insert-file-contents("https://melpa.org/packages/archive-contents")
package--download-one-archive(("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") "archive-contents")
#[0 "\301\300\302\"\207" [("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
package--download-one-archive "archive-contents"] 3 "\n\n(fn)"]()
funcall(#[0 "\301\300\302\"\207" [("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")   package--download-one-archive "archive-contents"] 3 "\n\n(fn)"])
package-refresh-contents()
list-packages(nil)
call-interactively(list-packages record nil)
command-execute(list-packages record)
execute-extended-command(nil "list-packages")
call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

and my `.emacs` file

```
(custom-set-variables
;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-archives
 (quote
(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
 ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))))
 (custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

Comment: Does MELPA accept https? http works OK - did you try that?

Comment: yes, the https like works properly on my machine

Comment: I had the same experience. I removed melpa from my list of package archives and proceeded as usual. The next day I put it back and it worked OK.
No comment on the underyling cause.

Answer (score 1):

i have found exactly where the problem is...to download the melpa list in emacs (emacs must access the internet) so you must include the library files to do that...download **gnutls-3.3.11-w32-bin** from here `https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/` ... extract the downloaded file... and put the `.dll` files in `bin` file in emacs folder...
hope you are happy with my little help :)

Comment: A similar error of mine ("fail to download 'melpa' archive") was solved by installing the most recent version of gnutls-bin (3.4.10-4ubuntu1.1) via Synaptic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on Win7 and [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/27251/17223) answer from StackExchange helped me.
In short, you have to download compiled Windows GnuTLS libraries and dependencies from [here](http://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/pretest/windows/) and unzip it to the emacs folder. Get `emacs-25-i686-deps.zip` if you use `32-bit` Windows and get `emacs-25-x86_64-deps.zip` if you use `64-bit`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. It could be a $PATH issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, since I was using Emacs 25.2 64-bit, I had to download the `emacs-25-x86_64-deps.zip` files from here:

https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/emacs-25/